# If I'm making a deck of cards how do I shuffle it as an ArrayList if I want my return to be an object of my class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make a method that creates a deck of cards and shuffles it. I want my return to be an object from my class, but I also want my deck of cards to be an ArrayList and I'm unsure how to do this.

Here is my method so far:

```
public static Cards makeFullDeck(){
   ArrayList<Card> temp = ArrayList<Card>();
    Cards deck = new Cards();
    for(Suit s: Suit.values()){
        for(Value v: Value.values()){
            deck.add(new Card(s,v)); 
        }
    }

    Collections.shuffle(temp);
    return deck;
}
```

the add method simply adds a card to the bottom of the pile and Cards is my class. I want the method to return an object of the class but I also want it to apply to arraylists, so that when I am making an arraylist in another class, I can call this method to create one. How do i go about fixing my code to do this?

Comment: Your `ArrayList` has no relationship to the `deck` object you're returning.  You're doing a *lot* of work to shuffle those cards, and the result of the shuffle is thrown away.

Answer (score -1):

In this case it would be best if you add a `shuffle()` method to the `Cards` class, that simply shuffles it's internal list:

```
class Cards {
  private List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

  public void shuffle() {
    Collections.shuffle(this.cards);
  }

  // All other code omitted for obvious reasons.
}
```

which you then invoke in your method:

```
deck.shuffle();
return deck;
```

An alternative (but probably inferior) solution would be to add the `Card` objects to a temporary list first, then shuffle that list, then add the cards to the `Cards`:

```
// Create temporary list with all cards.
List<Card> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Suit s: Suit.values()){
    for(Value v: Value.values()){
        tmpList.add(new Card(s,v)); 
    }
}

// Shuffle the cards.
Collections.shuffle(tmpList);

// Now stick them in the deck.
Cards deck = new Cards();
for (Card c : tmpList) {
  deck.add(c);
}

return deck;
```

Comment: It doesn't, also I'd like for the shuffling to be done withing the same method!

Comment: @raza no problem! Don't forget to vote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: Your original answer was better.  At least there, you had the right idea when stating that `Cards` should have a backing `List`, and that one should call `Collections#shuffle` in there.

Comment: @Makoto you are correct. Unfortunately that wasn't possible within the boundaries set by the OP though. I'll make a note of it though.